# Specified cast is not valid #2

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, casting

I have a stored procedure that returns a list of id and name.

```
TeamID(byte)   TeamName(string)
----------------------------------
1              baseball
2              basketball
```

and I have a drop down list which displays team names, but if a team capacity is full, the team name shouldn't be in the list.  I use this method to get the list of teams and add them to a Dictionary if the capacity of a team is not full, and then return the Dictionary.
The method looks like:

```
public Dictionary<byte, string> getTeamList()
{
    Dictionary<byte, int> capacityList = new Dictionary<byte, int>();
    var capacityQuery = _dataContext.usp_getTeamCapacityList();
    foreach(var item in capacityQuery)
    {
        capacityList.Add(item.TeamID, item.Capacity);
    }

    Dictionary<byte, string> result = new Dictionary<byte, string>();
    var sports = _dataContext.usp_getSports();
    foreach(var item2 in sports)
    {
        if(capacityList.ContainsKey(item2.TeamID)
        {
            int memberCount = _dataContext.usp_getNumberOfMemberPerTeam(item2.TeamID)
                .FirstOrDefault().MemberCount;
            if(capacityList[item2.TeamID] > memberCount)
            {
                result.Add(item2.TeamID, item2.TeamName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(item2.TeamID, item2.TeamName);
        }
    }
}
```

At the second foreach loop, the first item sometimes works, but I get `invalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`. When I comment out the first `foreach` loop, it works fine, but it seems that I get the invalidCastException error when I have both `foreach` loops.

It seems that it's complaining this part:

```
int memberCount = _dataContext.usp_getNumberOfMemberPerTeam(item2.TeamID)
    .FirstOrDefault().MemberCount;
```

The type of MemberCount is `int`. It works when I comment out this line of code.

Comment: Why don't you just select  teams which team capacity is not full from database?

Comment: I believe you have `else` block not on it's place

Comment: what line are  you getting the exception on...the foreach line itself, the if...

Comment: It's likely that `item.TeamID`, and `item2.TeamID` are not the same type.

Comment: What are the types of `capacityQuery` and `sports`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Nikola - please don't edit the code in the question like that. You could be obscuring the source of the problem.

Comment: @David Hope - I get the exception on the second foreach loop. On the foreach part.

Comment: @svick - I'm using Linq so the type of capacityQuery and sports is SingleResult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best solution but I changed my stored procedure to get count to this:

```
@SessionID INT
SELECT ID, COUNT(Member) AS Count
FROM   Table
WHERE  SessionID = @SessionID 
GROUP BY ID
```

which returns a table containing ID and the total count of Members for each ID

So, instead of getting values for the count per ID inside the foreach loop, I retrieve the list of ID and Count before entering the foreach loop and this works..

I still don't understand why I was getting the casting error, so I would mark it as answer if someone could explain what I was missing.